# Constant 'in' values as REST API value at ease

Tags: api, rest, sails.js

In this SailsJS Model, we are keeping the static option values in 'in' key attribute.

```
status: {
    type : 'string',
    defaultsTo : 'Active',
    in : ['Active', 'InActive']
}
```

Are these values are available in REST API -> preferably in /OPTIONS format?

Would like to offer One Source of Truth for these Constant Values. 
  Wanted to understand the best practices how these values can be sent via REST API for the Front End Application. When both front end application as well Thrid party API users can get the same source of truth, then its very easy to maintain the application. Please suggest.

Thanks and Regards, Raj

Comment: does this really have anything to do with `angularjs` ??

Comment: You'd rather use a boolean if you only have two options. `isActive: 'boolean'`

Comment: @YannBertrand I am starting with InActive, Active, But over the period , additional status like 'Deferred', 'Cancelled' etc will be required, Thats the reason, I am keeping String ..

Comment: @AbdelRaoof Nope .. this is SailsJS MVC Framework from SailsJS.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid you have to make an OptionController and manually do it. For these static options, you can write them in a config file, then access them with sails.config.xxx. For example:
In config/whatever.js

```
module.exports={
    activeChoices:['active','inactive','donotknow','xxx']
}
```

Create the OptionController.js, and set the route

Route.js

```
'GET /statusOptions/ :{
    controller:'OptionController',
    action:'statusOptions'
}
```

Then in your api/Controller/OptionController.js

```
module.exports={
    statusOptions:function(req,res){
        return res.json(sails.config.activeChoices);
    }
}
```

In your model

```
status:{type:'string',defaultsTo:'Active',in:sails.config.activeChoices}
```

Comment: Well.. That's a Separate Component By itself. I would like to bring those static values also a separate static value in MongoDb like JSON Store.. Then the second question on your point,  status: {
    type : 'string',
    defaultsTo : 'Active',
    in : { sails.config.activeChoices or sails.config.statusOptions }
} .. Will my assumption that inside in work or should i use sails.config.statusOptions here or something else. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can put these in a database and access them before the Models are initialized. but you can certainly use some non-sails way to access the database. For the 2nd point, the statusOptions is in optionController, so that when the client request http://localhost:1337/option/statusoptions/, you will get the options. in your model. check my update

Comment: Thank Evilsanta. I will check this sails.config.activeChoices

Comment: I think, i need to accept this as best possible answer to the question asked considering the SailsJS Framework. Not sure, whether i have enough StackOverflow reputation to accept. I am fine, if someone else accepts this as well.